# Importing Excel files into Access with Excel 2016

Tags: excel, shell, ms-access, vba

We currently have Office 2010 and are moving to Office 2016.  I have an Excel macro that I am try to testing.  I use the following shell command to open access and run a macro to import some excel files into a database.  This has worked great and never has any issues.

```
Shell "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE \\Vs300\rental_public\SHARED~1\SSDATA~2.MDB /X Upload_Manheim", vbMaximizedFocus
```

When I look for the Access application on my machine the path is as follows:

```
C:Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14
```

When I search for the Access application on the test machine, the path is as follows:

```
C:Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16
```

I've tried modifying the shell command as follows:

```
Shell "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE \\Vs300\rental_public\OFFICE~1\SHARED~1\SSDATA~1.MDB /X Upload_Manheim", vbMaximizedFocus
```

When I try to run my macro, I'm getting a file not found error message.  I believe the 2nd half of the shell command is fine, so I believe it is the issue is in the 1st half of the shell command.

The database being opened is an Access 2000 database.  I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: The MDB file is different in the second command. Is that on purpose?

Comment: When you paste the paths into Windows Explorer's navigation bar, do they take you to the correct folder?

Comment: Um. Why don't you use the **full** paths instead of these `PROGRA~1` things? It's not 1995 anymore. On 64bit Windows there are 2 "Program Files" folders, and `C:\PROGRA~1` probably points to the wrong one.

Comment: Have you checked that the path and filename that you have entered are correct?  (Use the `/X` switch with the DOS `DIR` command to show the short name for non-8dot3 files.)  Or just use the non-8dot3 filenames but wrap each one with double-quotation marks (double double-quotation marks within a literal), So `Shell """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSAccess.EXE"" ""\Vs300\...whatever...MDB"" /X Upload_Manheim"`.

Comment: @Andre............Thanks........After I posted the question, I did some more research and found a similar post and that was the solution.  Once I put in the full path name, it worked like I was expecting it to....

Comment: @YowE3K.....That is exactly what I ended up doing and it worked for me.  The original code was developed by someone else and I was just following what worked before.....

Comment: @ComIntern.........I hadn't thought of doing that but will definitely keep that in mind for the future....

Comment: @RobertF......Yes....it was done on purpose.  the current production machine has Office 2014 while the test machine has Office 2016....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going thru the command line you could stay inside your Excel Macro and do the same without making reference to the location of the Access application. Instead you can create a new instance of MS Access from within vba, open the Access database the contains the macro, and then run the macro.
Something like:

```
Dim accApp As Access.Application
Dim db As Object

Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "Your database location\dbName", True

Set db = accApp.CurrentDb
With db
    DoCmd.RunMacro "MacroNameHere" 
End With

Set accApp = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Good luck!

Comment: dont forget to add a reference to the Access object model!

Comment: @ErickTripleE..........thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up entering the full paths and it worked for me.  I will definitely keep this suggestion in mind for future development,  Thanks for the help....